# Angular Material: md-button ~ hoot change the text of the button based on input on NodeRed

Tags: javascript, angular-material, node-red

in NodeRed, I use the newish UI_Dashboard Template node, which use normal Angular Material notation for buttons etc, I have the following doing a working button:

```
<md-button
ng-style="{background: msg.payload=='0' ?'green':'red'}"
ng-click="msg.payload = (msg.payload=='0' ? send({payload: 'event,allsprinkleroff'}) : send({payload: 'event,allsprinkleroff'})) "
> Button Name
```

But, I want the 'Button Name' to change based on the incoming msg.payload value. Any ideas now? All my googling and searching here did not give me answers? (newbi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/GjROGa?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-button ng-style="{background: msg.payload=='0' ?'green':'red'}" ng-click="msg.payload =(msg.payload=='0' ? send({payload: 'event,allsprinkleroff'}) : send({payload:'event,allsprinkleroff'})) ">Payload {{msg.payload}}</md-button>

  <br>
  <md-button ng-click="togglePayLoad()">Toggle Payload</md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = {
    payload: 0
  }

  $scope.togglePayLoad = function () {
    $scope.msg.payload = ($scope.msg.payload === 0) ? 1 : 0;
  }
});
```